# Filter grouped data to exclude too few or too many entries

Tags: r, grouping, subset

I have data, where there are typically 5 lines for each subject (subject a). Some subjects have abortes the participation and therefore have fewer lines (subject b) and some participated multiple times (but can be differentiated by timestamps; subject c).

```
dd <- data.frame(subject_id = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",4),rep("c",10)), date = c(rep("date1",5),rep("date2",4),rep("date3",5),rep("date4",5)))

  subject_id  date
1           a date1
2           a date1
3           a date1
4           a date1
5           a date1
6           b date2
7           b date2
8           b date2
9           b date2
10          c date3
11          c date3
12          c date3
13          c date3
14          c date3
15          c date4
16          c date4
17          c date4
18          c date4
19          c date4
```

I need to exclude lines where there are fewer than 5 entries which I have achieved with

```
dd <-  dd %>% group_by(subject_id) %>% filter(n()>=5)
```

So far so good. For those instances where there are more than 5 lines I do not want to exclude all of the entries but keep either the first 5 or the last 5. Have not managed to do this so far. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can add a condition with `row_number` in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
     group_by(subject_id) %>% 
     filter(n() >=5, row_number() <=5)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
# Groups:   subject_id [2]
#   subject_id date 
#   <chr>      <chr>
# 1 a          date1
# 2 a          date1
# 3 a          date1
# 4 a          date1
# 5 a          date1
# 6 c          date3
# 7 c          date3
# 8 c          date3
# 9 c          date3
#10 c          date3
```

---

Or to get the last 5 rows

```
dd %>%
    group_by(subject_id) %>%
    filter(n() >= 5,  rev(row_number()) <=5)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for!